# Try Catch statement realBasic

Tags: basic, realbasic, xojo

I am trying to wrap up simple statement within try catch. Problem is that all examples that I was able to find talk about the errors which are predefined.

I need a generic error, similar to try/catch in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a generic try catch you can do this:

```
try

  ...put some code here

catch

  ...do something for ANY exception here.

finally

  ...code here that runs IF an exception occurs

end try
```

The catch section has optional parameters to catch certain types of errors (the examples you've seen).  The first paragraph gives the definition at http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/Try

```
Try

// Your code

Catch [ErrorParameter] [As ErrorType]

//exception handlers

[ Finally ]

//code that executes even if runtime exceptions were raised

End [Try]
```